# How can I do to put a value by default for the map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React.js and I

```
myArray.map(variable=>({value: variable.value, label: variable.label}))
```

everything is ok but sometimes I have the following case : `TypeError : myArray is null`

How can I do to put a default value or something like this ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this error, you have to to implement a check before you run the `map` function.

If you are doing it outside JSX, as it seems in your code then the code should look like:

```
if (myArray && myArray.length > 0) {
   myArray.map(variable=>({value: variable.value, label: variable.label}))
}
```

And if you are doing it inside JSX, then the code should look like:

```
myArray && myArray.length > 0 && myArray.map((...your code...))
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending [Shafayet's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14265453/shafayet2368) answer,

- If you're using es6, you can use optional chaining. Like this:

  `myArray?.map(variable=>({value: variable.value, label: variable.label}))`
- Not the best solution but works with OR (||) operator when myArray is null:

  `(myArray || []).map(variable=>({value: variable.value, label: variable.label}))`